# PyCharm Sqlalchemy - add data via terminal

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm

so I've installed venv and then SQLalchemy

then I have written a piece of Python code in Pycharm:

```js
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (
            self.name, self.fullname, self.password)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

users = session.query(User).all()
for user in users:
    print("User #%d with username=%s" % (user.id, user.name))

session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Now I want to add a User via PyCharm terminal:

```
user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', password='edspassword')
```

But I'm getting an error:

*'user' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Terminal is not a Python console, it is the OS terminal (looks like `cmd.exe` in your case).

Comment: That is certainly cmd.exe my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Type in python before to access python console.

```
C:.../>python
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', password='edspassword')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a console available at the bottom of the Window. Or at least should be. If not, in the terminal Window type

`python`

Afterward you need to import your models file, on my server I would do this like:

`from app.models import User`

Then you can:

`user = User(...)`

In your case I think you may need to `cd` to the directory which has the file with the code you posted above in it.

Then you can do `python` and import the file directly. Once done you'll have access to your `class` in the console and you could manually add users.

However, if you right click on the database, you are able to connect to it (if it's local) and administer changes directly to the rows themselves.

[UPDATE]

Go to the terminal -->

type `cd C:\\path\to\pyfile` -->

type `python` -->

type `import mypyfile` and then you should have your User class

[ALTERNATE METHOD]

You could also, directly from the terminal,

`cd C:\\...\...\pyfile`

`python myfile.py`

Also, make sure you activate you `venv` before you try the above as I can wager a guess that it will fail because sqlalchemy isn't installed (but it is, just in the venv).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! I knew I have to import something. But I don't have app.models (I'm not using Flask in this case). I only have a folder 1.py file in my root folder which has the class. So how do I do then? "from 1.py import User" - doesn't work...

Comment: Updating my answer. One moment please.

Comment: @Andrey Kurnikovs please read updated answer. Let me know if you are still struggling

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I've actually figured out: first from my project folder I need to activate my virtual environment `source ~/venv/scripts/activate`, then type `python`, after that `import myfilename` (without ".py"). And from there on I can `from myfilename import Users`

Answer (score 0):

I've actually figured it out: (I was using GitBash this time)

first from my project folder I need to activate my virtual environment `source ~/venv/scripts/activate`,

then type `python`,

after that `import myfilename` (without ".py"),

and from there on I can `from myfilename import User`

now the `user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', password='edspassword')` works just fine :)

Comment: And in order to add a user to the database I also need to `from test import session
` and then >>>`session.add(ed_user)` and >>>`session.commit()`

Comment: from myfilename import User*